# Binary search for zero in data.table 1.9.4 in R has unexpected behavior

Tags: r, data.table

I don't understand the difference between 0 and 0L in data.table's binary search.

Try to explain it with a small example.

```
DT <- data.table(a = c(0, 1.5, 2, 1), b = c(0L:3L))
str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  0 1.5 2 1
 $ b: int  0 1 2 3
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
DT[a == 1.5, a := 1]
DT[a == 1]
   a b
1: 1 1
2: 1 3
```

At this point everything is fine but ...

```
DT[a == 2, a := 0]
DT[a == 0]
   a b
1: 0 0
DT[a == 0L]
   a b
1: 0 0
2: 0 2
str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  0 1 0 1
 $ b: int  0 1 2 3
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "index")= atomic  
  ..- attr(*, "a")= int  1 4 2 3
```

Huh, the variable a is numeric but I get the 'correct' answer when searching for an integer?

And vice versa:

```
DT[b == 2L, b := 0L]
DT[b == 0L]
   a b
1: 0 0
DT[b == 0]
   a b
1: 0 0
2: 0 0
str(DT)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: num  0 1 0 1
 $ b: int  0 1 0 3
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
 - attr(*, "index")= atomic  
  ..- attr(*, "a")= int  1 4 2 3
  ..- attr(*, "b")= int
```

It would be quite nice if someone could clarify this behavior.
Thanks

Comment: +1 Interestingly, `DT[, a == 0]` returns `[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`. I'd suggest to report this to the data.table bug tracker.

Comment: Did you try with the development version? I get different results with version 1.9.5.

Comment: For your clarification: This is not binary search, but a vector scan.

Comment: @Roland, it uses binary search underneath by setting a secondary key automatically.

Comment: using setkey(DT, "a") respectively setkey(DT, "b") before the binary search gives better results

Comment: @Arun Ah, okay. Thanks. I should peruse the NEWS files again.