# In data.table I can't select rows using column names

Tags: r, data.table

I create data.table d using following code:

```
require("ltm")
require("data.table")
require(psych)

data(LSAT)
d = data.table(LSAT)
d[,"Item 6" := 0]
d[1, "Item 6"] = 1

> sapply(d,class)
   Item 1    Item 2    Item 3    Item 4    Item 5    Item 6 
"integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "numeric"
```

Then, I can filter rows using column "Item 6" ceated by me.

```
> d["Item 6" == 1]
   Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Item 5 Item 6
1:      0      0      0      0      0      1
```

But I can't do the same using columns that are in the dataset by default, e.g. "Item 1"

```
> d["Item 1" == 1]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 6 cols: Item 1,Item 2,Item 3,Item 4,Item 5,Item 6
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The answer from Sven is most likely not the right answer. And this issue is likely the cause of a bug due to a new feature automatic indexing which has since then been fixed in the current development version. And therefore is most likely a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27012051/559784).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to compare the integers in column `Item 1` with an integer (`1L`). Note that `1` is a double value. It worked for column `Item 6` since it is of class `numeric` (`double`).

```
d["Item 1" == 1L]
```

The result:

```
     Item 1 Item 2 Item 3 Item 4 Item 5 Item 6
  1:      1      0      0      0      0      0
  2:      1      0      0      0      0      0
  3:      1      0      0      0      0      0
  4:      1      0      0      0      0      0
  5:      1      0      0      0      0      0
 ---                                          
920:      1      1      1      1      1      0
921:      1      1      1      1      1      0
922:      1      1      1      1      1      0
923:      1      1      1      1      1      0
924:      1      1      1      1      1      0
```

Comment: Interesting - seems unexpected since `1 == 1L` is `TRUE`. Is `data.table` using `identical` behind the scenes?

Comment: Nope. Nothing to do with `identical()`.